Is it possible to have a different background colour for each row in a SwiftUI NavigationStack List on iOS?
I am a complete novice to Swift and I am writing a very simple application in SwiftUI for iOS 17 on Xcode 15.4. I would like to change the background colour of each row in a NavigationStack List to a colour name held in a string variable within a class. The data displayed in the list is pulled from an array of this class.
I have tried the following code which I expected to show a different colour on each row. The colour name is held in the MeritCard class in the name string.
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query(sort: \MeritCard.rank) var meritcards: [MeritCard]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(meritcards) {meritcard in
                    VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(meritcard.name)
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(Color(meritcard.name.lowercased()))
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Your Meritcards")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Add Samples", action: addSamples)
            }
        }
    }

I am using .listRowBackground(Color(meritcard.name.lowercased())) to attempt to alter the colour.
The code compiles fine but the background colour of each row remains white.

With the answer from @workingdog-support you are almost done. Just one tip: I would define a function (MeritCard) -> Color in your ContentView in order to move the "appearance logic" into the view ContentView , so that the model  can be kept "clean" from appearance related properties.

fair enough comment.  Note, if you have a large number of names/colors, then I have an alternative approach
if you are interested.

Thank you @CouchDeveloper for your tip. I have implemented your suggestion.

Yes it is possible to have a different background colour for each row in a List.
You have to add the colors to your Assets.xcassets using the
New Color Set (right mouse click on the left panel).
Select the appearance and choose/adjust the color from the right panel. Give the colors the same name as in your MeritCard.
So given your have created for example "gold", "silver", .... colors
in your Assets.xcassets and also have the same name in your MeritCard,
your code should work and show the different colors
according to the names. Works well for me.

Thank you very much @workingdog-support your solution works perfectly.

If my answer helped you, consider accepting it by ticking the tick mark next ot it, it turns green.
